# Apache httpclient GET response entity content is empty

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, http-request

I use Apache httpclient and httpcore to implement HTTP requests in my project.
Recently I find this issue: I have a method with this body

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    try {       
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);

        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
        Header[] h = response.getAllHeaders();
        for (int i = 0; i < h.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(h[i].getName());
        }
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream content = entity.getContent();
        System.out.println(entity.getContentLength());

        org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup
                .parse(convertStreamToString(content));

        System.out.println(convertStreamToString(content));
        EntityUtils.consume(entity);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
```

with a valid URL but the content is empty and the status code is 200.

I try with the firefox plugin RESTClient and a simple GET request with the same URL and no headers works(content response isn't empty).

Also re-sending Get request with firefox debugger works(this time with default headers already present).

Ps: I obviously try to add all headers but nothing :(

Can someone help me with the Apache components?

Answer (score 0):

I solved: the method convertStreamToString(content) edited the content so was enough call the method only one time(or use other variables obv).